# Convert timestamp into hour with PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

Hi I am using following way to convert timestamp into hour:

```
 echo time() / 3600 % 24;
```

This return like **7** if its 7 GTM but I need its output such as **07:00**

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this with  `gmdate` function

```
echo gmdate("H:i", time());
```

if you want only hours than just have only `H` in `gmdate`

> [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) — Format a GMT/UTC date/time

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YnAEqG)

As  [@Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476521/convert-timestamp-into-hour-with-php/33476596?noredirect=1#comment54738320_33476596) suggest if you want fix second timer than you can manually write like

```
echo gmdate("H:00", time());
```

Comment: I think this is what I am trying for I need 11 irrespective of minutes ie if its 11:45 I still need 11 so I tried above code using only "H"  and it worked.

Comment: Thanks but it still returns 11 only I need like 11:00 (zero formats ) please suggest

Comment: whether its 11:35 but my requirement is having 11:00

Comment: `echo gmdate("H:00", time());`

Comment: Is that will also work in case if we have 7 and it will show like 07:00

Comment: Thanks all for help  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date('h:i', time());
```

Or, if you want it to always be :00 you can just do:

```
echo date('h', time()) . ':00';
```

If you want it to always be GMT, then you can use [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).

Comment: If I use like above for current GMT time it returns 12 which is not true but when I use like my code mentioned in question it returns 11 which is required time.

Comment: You can use gmdate() instead if you want it to always be GMT.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well !